# Hide Outgoing Call Screen in iOS

Tags: ios

I am facing a problem from last 2 days. According to my requirement when I call to another number through coding, I have to call directly without showing Call Screen. When I pressed the call button then call will be transfer in Background. The Call screen will not be shown on screen.

My code for call on Button:

```
 - (IBAction)callBtn_Action:(id)sender
 {
    NSString *phNo = @"02233814006";
    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phNo]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl])
    {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *calert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Call facility is not available!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [calert show];
    }
 }
```

Is it possible? Please anybody help me..

Comment: From my understanding of your question, you want to control the presence of the native call screen in iOS? While I've never tried to do so, I'm confident to say that it is not possible to do. And it never will be (bold claim).

Comment: Ok thank you @ MartinHN

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support directly calling a number. The best you can do is show the screen with a populated number to dial. There is no work around for this.